# Somar valor nulo Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Eu estou tentando fazer a seguinte soma com Query Builder, mas se um dos valores for nulo e não soma

```
DB::raw("estudantes_carga_horaria.dias_letivos_oferecidos + estudantes_carga_horaria.dias_letivos_oferecidos_outra_escola AS total_dias_letivos_oferecidos")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o Coalesce, que colocará `0` quando o valor for `null`.

```
DB::raw("
COALESCE(estudantes_carga_horaria.dias_letivos_oferecidos, 0) + 
COALESCE(estudantes_carga_horaria.dias_letivos_oferecidos_outra_escola, 0)
AS total_dias_letivos_oferecidos")
```

Estou respondendo o que você perguntou, mas possivelmente tem outros jeitos de fazer dependendo do que você quer com esse valor.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!